# Reflexive love: where does "love me some ..." come from?

Tags: etymology, verbs, slang, reflexives

It seems trendy to use a reflexive-like construction with *love* or *hate* plus *some*, like this:

- You know I love me some cheese!
- I hate me some cold and the temperature is dropping.

Where did this come from and why has it become popular?

Comment: I've also heard "I'm gonna get me some" or "I'm gonna take me some" used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's wrong with "I'll open you the door"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think this is a dupe of the linked question at all. This Q relates to a particular construction whereas the linked Q is about something else entirely. They do both deal with personal pronouns, but they're not the same question.

Comment: I wonder whether it is not also related to the so-called _ethic dative_, of which the OED says, _s.v._ **me**, _pron., 1d_: "Used expletively in passages of a narrative character." Example (from Swift): "Then whips me on a Chain of Brass."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To give it a name, the construction is called the "[Personal Dative](http://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/personal-datives)" and is loosely attributed to [African American Vernacular English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) and some other Southern white dialects. The construction, as in your example, works with a typically non-reflexive verb (popular verbs in these dialects are simple: get, find, have, use, take, love, buy, shoot, and kill, which is kilt in the past tense) and a subject pronoun. PDs in 1st person singular are most common, and PDs in 2nd person are more common than 3rd person.

1st Person:

> I had me a man in summertime/He had summer-colored skin (Joni
>   Mitchell, “Urge for Going”)

2nd Person:

> Get you a copper kettle, O get you a copper coil, Cover with new-made
>   corn mash and never more you’ll toil. You just lay there by the
>   junipers, when the moon is bright, Watch them jugs a-ﬁllin’ in the
>   pale moonlight. (“Copper Kettle”, traditional ballad)

3rd Person:

> Born on a mountain top in Tennessee, The greenest state in the land of
>   the free, Raised in the woods so’s he knew every tree, Kilt
>   him a b’ar when he was only three. (“Ballad of Davy Crockett”; cf. M.
>   Lewis 2002)

There is debate over whether the PD is an indirect object, as it appears in an example like:

> I caught **me** some fish.

Or, if it is a pronoun, as it appears in this example with a true indirect object:

> I caught **me** some fish *for my family*.

Other things worth noting about this dialectical usage of the PD are:

1.) There is no passive construction. "Some fish were caught (to) me."

2.) PDs cannot be split apart from the verb that marks them. "I caught some fish, me."

3.) They are always unstressed. "I CAUGHT me some fish" and not "I caught ME some fish."

4.) Deciding on the pronomial status of the PD has become more difficult with the evolution of the newly-popularized *X's-ass* construction. [Bear with me] "I have a 152 IQ and I love my ass some red meat." This *X's ass* construction apparently does not show up in 3rd person constructions and rarely in 2nd person.

Dating it is extremely difficult, as Robusto mentions, and many of the earliest references are traditional ballads and folk songs.

For a thorough discussion on the topic, check out this [link](http://www.cssp.cnrs.fr/eiss7/horn-eiss7.pdf).

Comment: Re your #3, I don't see why it shouldn't be stressed in, for example, "so I got ME a drink too". Which occurs in that link at some point after *I had fresh water to drink any time I wanted to get me a drink* (proof that the writer uses this form quite naturally).

Comment: In the more "down home," simple constructions the idea is that the PD doesn't receive stress. As the construction becomes more complex, this varies. "He bought him and Tony some steaks." Some stress on "him", but if "and Tony" is removed, perhaps not.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably rural- or African-American speech that parallels other constructions like *get me some X* and *drink me some X* and so on.

The usage has been around for a while. Here is [an example](http://books.google.co.nz/books?ei=zPC4UMPOCYbK0AHJvoHwAw&id=opYuAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22Yeah%2C+chile%2C+I+love+me+some+poke+chops.+I+could+just+eat+them+till+I+bust.%22&q=%22Yeah%2C+chile%2C+I+love+me+some+poke+chops.+I+could+just+eat+them+till+I+bust.%22#search_anchor) from 1971:

> Yeah, chile, I love me some poke chops.

(The *poke* chops in question are obviously *pork* chops, but that is more evidence that this is rural or African-American speech.)

Comment: Seems to make more sense with *get*; nobody would question *I'm going to get myself some dinner*, and it's easy to see *me* being substituted for *myself*.

Comment: Cat Stevens (a Brit) wrote ["I'm Gonna Get Me A Gun"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I'm_Gonna_Get_Me_a_Gun) in 1967, and Fielding's *The Virgin Unmasked* has ["I'll get me a Husband"](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iYJYZwLCVf0C&pg=PA124&dq=%22I'll+warrant+I'll+get+me+a+husband%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-jm5UNL0MIfD0QWd5IDADw&ved=0CEoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22I'll%20warrant%20I'll%20get%20me%20a%20husband%22&f=false) in C18, so I don't think the form is particularly young, American, or black.

Comment: ...but here's Texas governor [Fritz G. Lanham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fritz_G._Lanham) (who *graduated from the University of Texas at Austin with a B.A. in 1900*, so he's no cotton-pickin' hick), with the immortal lines [Very well," said Hephaestus, who beamed with delight, " I will drink me some coffee and sit up tonight. And will finish the suit by the first streak of light](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+will+drink+me+some+coffee%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Doggerel maybe, but presumably Lanham didn't think it was "African-American".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I didn't say it was young. Read again. Also, who says you can't graduate from the University of Texas and be a hick. The President of the United States from 2001-2009 was a hick, and he had degrees from Harvard and Yale.

Comment: Perhaps. But there's no doubt the basic "superfluously reflexive" form has been around a long time with verbs like *get, have, eat, drink, watch, take,* etc. And although *love*, for example, sounds like a "tolerable" stretch (maybe associated with Texans/blacks/hicks/whatever) I have the distinct feeling all instances of *hate me some xxx* are just a modern facetious Internet-enabled viral meme.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know how facetious it is, but there is definitely a resurgence in this trope thanks to mass media of all kinds, including but not limited to the Internet.

Comment: I guess - I can't *begin* to explain why *love* "sorta" works for me, whereas *hate* sounds a bit ridiculous. So maybe younger speakers don't see they're crossing any particular Rubicon there. But they certainly seem to include *"some"* nearly every time - though I get the feeling speakers are divided on whether they're using it to modify **how much** they love/hate/whatever, or whether it modifies/limits **the thing** loved or hated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Regarding Cat Stevens, do recall that British pop/rock music has for a long time been influenced by black American speech patterns. Look at all the British rockers who tried to sing with a southern American twang, from John Lennon to Eric Clapton to Robert Plant to Elton John — the list goes on and on.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the image, but [this link](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3oqf2r/) is titled *I Hate Memes - yo i **hate me some memes***.

The tagline for that site is *"Create and share memes instantly with our quick meme generator"*, so I'm putting that up as a possible "source".

Seriously, I think looking for the "original" with things like this is a bit like asking ["where do jokes come from?"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22where%20do%20jokes%20come%20from%22&oq=%22where%20do%20jokes%20come%20from%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.8410&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)