# "had me a blast" - what use of "have" is it?

Tags: meaning, verbs, synonyms

Reading the Summer love lyrics, the lyrics go as follows: "summer love, had me a blast". I know that "have a blast" means to enjoy etc. But I do not think I could say "it has me a blast".

Comment: "Me" is a shortening of "myself", a reflexive pronoun.

Comment: Related (in respect of this "non-standard" insertion of *"me"*) - [What's wrong with “I'll open you the door”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door)

Answer (score 7):

Even in spoken English or plain prose, we would drop pronouns - particularly *I* - [in some situations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/why-is-there-omission-of-subject-in-sentences-like-thought-youd-never-ask).

Here, "had me a blast" is doing this to "I had me a blast".

"I had me" in turn is an informal variant on "I had" found in some dialects, that adds emphasis.

So, "I had a blast".

Comment: Thanks. However I perceive "have" mainly in the meaning "to posses something"..would not "get" be better?

Comment: No, "a blast" means a good time, and *have* can cover experiences.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence means *I had me a blast*.

The subject *I* is understood.  While the reflexive *me* is not standard usage, the slang inclusion is used for emphasis.