# 'Ask' and its objects

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammar, verbs, writing-style

I'd like to know if the objects of the verb 'ask' **must** follow an order. If so what is that order? Should the first object be the person (someone) or the thing (something)?

For example: *Will you ask for that money to your mother?* or *Will you ask your mother for that money?*

Comment: You don't "ask money", you "ask a question" or "ask *for* money".

Comment: yeah it's true, thank you! I was copying a question from one of my students exercises and I let that one slip.

Comment: Likewise, no matter what you do, you do not ask *to* your mother. You ask your mother. Transitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the order matters to some extent. Consider the following:

> Ask for money.
>   Ask your mother.
>   Ask Tuesday.
>   Ask on Tuesday for money.
>   Ask for money on Tuesday.
>   Ask your mother for money on Tuesday.
>   Ask your mother on Tuesday for money.
>   On Tuesday ask your mother for money.
>   Ask your mother for money.
>   Ask for money from your mother.

All the above are understandable.

The last form is rather ambiguous, you could be asking your brother to give you money that came from your mother. The penultimate sentence is preferable.

So, most often, You'd place the recipient of the request earlier in the sentence than what is being requested. Usually the recipient of the request would be first.

There are definitely preferred orders for sentences of this form but I don't know of any firm rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is a transitive, but **not** bi- (or di-) transitive, use of the verb *ask*.
I.e, in this context it means 'request', rather than 'address a question to someone', and it has only a direct object,
rather than bitransitive *ask*, which has both direct **and** indirect objects.

- *She asked Harry what the answer was.*
  (bitransitive: *Harry* = indirect object, *what the answer was* = direct object)
- *She asked Harry for some help with her homework*.
  (transitive: *Harry* = direct object)

The thing that's requested is the object of *for*, and in fact if the object is indefinite, obvious, or irrelevant, it can be deleted, making *ask for* effectively equivalent to *request*.

- *She asked for/requested some help with her homework.*

Comment: _Ask_ can even be tritransitive, am I correct? _She asked Harry for the dirty on her husband._

Comment: @Talia Ford: No - here, for instance, 'on her husband' is an adjectival modifying 'the dirty'. This example isn't even ditransitive. Compare _She asked Harry for some news about her husband._ with _She asked Harry for some help with her homework._ above.

Comment: There are no tritransitive verbs, to my knowledge, in any language. 1, 2, or 3 arguments, that's it. (Well, there are impersonals like _It's raining_ that have no arguments; but that's a very small set of constructions.) For details see the [Logic Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and the [Verb Phrase Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf)

Comment: I thank both of you for being forthcoming. Respect.
(I also feel a little stupid, but that's okay. Live to learn and you'll learn to live.)

Comment: No need to feel stupid; grammar is complicated stuff, and most English speakers are clueless about it because it's not taught in Anglophone schools.

Comment: @John Lawler: How many arguments would you say _Mike put me a bottle under the counter_ (which is certainly quite acceptable in N England) has?

Comment: That's a transform of _Mike put a bottle under the counter for me_, with the benefactive _for me_ triggering the [Dative Alternation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299) because you wind up possessing the bottle. So it's technically only transitive: _Mike_ = Su, _a bottle_ = DO. The benefactive-to-dative transformation essentially adds _me_ = IO, but that's derived, not basic.

Comment: But then you could argue that all ditransitives, being 'derived not basic', should be considered merely transitives?

Comment: No. There are real verbs like _give_ and _tell_ that always have IOs, whether they're present in a sentence or not. The Dative alternation applies to them all. It can also be applied to any benefactive _for_ phrase that has the same effect as a Dative, of transferring the DO to an individual. It's a special case, applied only to benefactives. Languages are full of things like that.

Comment: As is often the case, I'm struggling to reconcile different treatments I've come across in different grammars here. For instance, I've met the 'syntactic but not semantic' label being applied to 'direct objects' - I've even seen 'He led them a merry dance' labelled as ditransitive, when I'd definitely class 'a merry dance' as an adverbial objective, an ellipted form of 'in/on a merry dance'.

Comment: I don't know where the term "adverbial objective" comes from, but I'd just call _a merry dance_ a noun phrase, and I'd agree it's the object of a deleted preposition. But it's not an argument of the predicate _lead_, any more than _Tuesday_ would be; hence I wouldn't want to call it an "object" (or an "objective", which I presume means 'something "object"-like', like "gerund" and "gerundive"). Not a precise term, really.

Comment: The fact that there are so many different grammatical terms, all from different versions of "English grammar", with usually incompatible uses and understandings, is one of the reasons why the question/answer format is not ideal for discussing English grammar.

Comment: You must have examined different (approaches to) grammar in the many years you've spent studying the field. So have others, who are equally authoritative, but have come to prefer sometimes different analyses. Have you a pointer to laymen as to why grammar H say is to be preferred?

Comment: "Grammar H say"?

Comment: @John Lawler Sorry - I taught maths. Math. Just an 'unknown marker'. Is there any particular 'version of "English grammar" ' that you think interprets overall English usage best?

Comment: I think McCawley's _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_ (2nd ed 1998, Chicago) does the job admirably. Of course it's not a usage manual; it's a grammar. It's in fact a college textbook, for a one-year course in English grammar and syntax in general. About as long and as hard as, say, a one-year course in topology, with set theory and foundations thrown in.

Comment: Thank you. I may sling out one or two others if I find a reasonably inexpensive copy.

Comment: You can start with my [logic guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and [verb phrase guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), to give you the flavor; they're based on the same theory as McCawley, with less attention to finegrain detail. I developed them as remedial materials for syntax students, covering what they should have learned in grammar school, if there were such a thing.