# Is the verb 'inquire' bitransitive?

Tags: verbs, transitivity

People say the verb ***inquire*** can be bitransitive (i.e., ditransitive) and also monotransitive. I can find many examples of its monotransitive use, but none about bitransitive.

Could you show me how it is used as a bitransitive verb?

Comment: Who are these people?

Comment: What is the difference between bitransitive and ditransitive? Both mean 'two'.

Comment: @Oldcat I think that's what OP is saying: it can be [bitransitive, which some people call ditransitive] or monotransitive.

Comment: @Oldcat: I think they're just alternatives for the same thing. Me, I'm having trouble thinking of even a *transitive* usage that's not hopelessly obsolete. How on earth could you use it ditransitively? Janice - I think you need to give some evidence that anyone really does think these things.

Comment: As far as I know, inquire isn't used ditransitively (or bitransitively!). *Ask* is used both di- and monotransitively, but not *inquire*, unless you count prepositional phrases: *I inquired **of them** whether the train was on time.*

Comment: I'm also bi-transitive-curious.

Comment: @PeterShor Apparently, [John Lawler](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138157/verbs-with-two-direct-objects#comment283743_138157) (gasp!).

Comment: A note on terminology (at least, as standard amongst linguists).  Ditransitives take _two_ objects: e.g., _give_ + _the dog_ + _a bone_. Transitives (occasionally, monotransitives) take _one_ object: e.g., _gnaw_ + _a bone_.  Intransitives take no object: e.g., _arrive_.  StoneyB's link to John Lawler's use notwithstanding, I've never seen _bitransitive_ in any professional publication in my field.

Comment: Here is the comment I found from this site. They are not two direct objects, despite their case marking in German. The addressee is the indirect object, and the question is the direct object. I hypothesize that fragen allows doppelt Akkusativ in German (I don't know and you didn't give an example), but case is not function. It's a standard bitransitive communication verb, like say, tell, shout, inquire, etc. –  John Lawler Nov 18 '13 at 15:00

Comment: I'm pretty sure that different linguists define 'transitive' etc in confusingly different ways.

Answer (score 4):

*Inquire* is neither *ditransitive* nor *monotransitive*.^ A ditransitive verb is one like *give* (in some of its uses) that takes two objects:

> I gave the dog a bone.

A monotransitive (or plain transitive) takes just one object, as *gnaw* does (in some of its uses):

> The dog gnawed the bone.

*Inquire* can't be inserted into either of these syntactic frames in modern English (but see StoneyB’s answer and rogermue’s dated *enquire the time*):

> *I inquired the time.
>
> *I inquired the boy the time.

Instead, complements of *inquire* must be sentential for direct objects (the object of inquiry) or prepositional (the person to whom the inquiry is directed):

> I inquired what the time was.
>
> I inquired of the boy what the time was.

In a certain sense, *inquire* isn’t intransitive, then, either (as *arrive* is).  Rather, its semantic argument is subject to a syntactic restriction: it can only be expressed by a *sentential complement* (*what the time was*), not by a noun phrase (*the time*).  This contrasts with *ask* which is happy either with sentential or nominal complements:

> I asked the time.
>
> I asked what the time was.
>
> I asked the boy the time.
>
> I asked the boy what the time was.

The syntactic contrast between *ask* and *inquire* (and other pairs of verbs), which obtains despite their semantic similarity, was the subject of an important [paper](http://web.mit.edu/norvin/www/24.902/Grimshaw.pdf) in theoretical linguistics by Jane Grimshaw.

---

^ I've never heard the term *bitransitive* in any grammatical work.  So, I'll leave it aside in favour of *ditransitive*.

Answer (score 3):

In Present-Day English, *inquire* is not used  ditransitively (or bitransitively!) as, for instance, *ask* is. The person to whom you direct your inquiry is expressed with a preposition phrase:

> I inquired **of them** whether the train was on time.

This was not always the case, however. According to [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdicpt205murruoft#page/322/mode/2up), *s.v.* **Enquire**, that person might at least as late as 1682 be expressed in the same way as person of whom one *asks*:

> [The Bible] was fram'd at first our Oracle t'enquire.

And OED (**2.c.**) even gives an instance, from 1400-1450, of actual ditransitivity ('with dative of person, or double object'):

> ***a***  **1400-50**  *Alexander* 1110 Enquire me noȝt þat question, for I queth þe it neuer.

Comment: It’s not even all that transitive: just go ahead and try inquiring something.  It feels funny at best.

Comment: @tchrist Quite (though again, that's a ModE development). But you inquire *whether* something is true, and that's a free relative clause, which is a nominal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two spellings: to enquire and to inquire, especially American English.
to enquire can have a lot of preposition objects (about sth, after sb, of sb whether, into sth)
and it can have two objects ( to enquire sth of/from sb)
- He enquired the time from a passer-by. (elevated style)

Comment: But what class of objects? If they're 'oblique', does this preclude the classifications 'transitive' and 'ditransitive'?

Comment: You have a sentence: He enquired the time from a passer-by. The first object is an accusative-object, the second a preposition-object. But I think that can be seen.

Comment: But this still doesn't directly address OP's 'Could you show me how [enquire] is used as a bitransitive verb?' 'From a passer-by' would usually be classed as an oblique object as a PP. I assume 'asked/enquired the time' is possibly classed as a DO construction – though Aarts and others have queried the broad-brush classification of ([S +] V + NP) strings as necessarily containing direct objects. They say that it is a poor approach not to consider thematic roles before applying labels such as 'direct object'.