# What type of phrase is the highlighted part in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, phrases

She asked (me) **a difficult question.**

Comment: It's a noun phrase acting as the direct object of the transitive verb _asked._ The verb _asked_ here is amenable to "Dative Alternation", and so you could write your sentence in this way also: _She asked a difficult question of me_, though the former version is prefered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [verbs with two direct objects?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138157/verbs-with-two-direct-objects) ({not two direct objects] ... The addressee is the indirect object, and the question is the direct object.  ... It's a standard bitransitive communication verb, like say, tell, shout, inquire, etc. – J Lawler)

Comment: I agree with you and said many times on Facebook group this is ( noun phrase) object of the verb ask, but Iraqi students always are not satisfied thinking as a phrase begins with an adjective it should be (( adjective phrase )). This is not correct I know that the ( Head ) is a noun ( question ). Adjective phrases are formed as : Adv + adj  examples : very good , extremely difficult OR prepositional phrases act adjective