# Is "cry" an intransitive verb, or can it be transitive? - as in "Cry me a river"

Tags: grammar, verbs, parts-of-speech

When I look up the word, it should be an intransitive verb (no object). However, I'm still curious about the title "Cry me a river". Can I say that "I cried a bucket"?

Comment: What do the dictionaries say?

Comment: @bib How on earth would a dictionary be able to help with such a query?

Comment: I lack the grammatical chops to properly cite or defend this statement, so I'm going to leave it as a comment, but: I don't think it's the verb "*cry*" there that's doing something special. I think it's the construction "<intransitive-verb> *me*", which expands to "<intransitive-verb> ***for** me*". As in "***Swim me** a lap* in five seconds" or "***Die me** a death* that will be remembered forever".

Comment: @WS2 ODO says: [OBJECT]
Shed tears, especially as an expression of distress or pain:
*don’t cry—it’ll be all right*; 
[WITH OBJECT]: *you’ll cry tears of joy*. It obviously can be transitive.

Comment: @DanBron have [this fine pile of grammatical chops](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/300): "a Benefactive construction, which uses *for* instead of *to*, identifies someone for whose benefit something is done. This can be added to any sentence, transitive or intransitive. In precisely those situations where the Benefactive object of *for* ends up possessing the direct object, the sentences can undergo Dative; in those cases where they don't, they can't."

Comment: @Reg, Nice find! Should we mark this as a dupe then?

Comment: @Dan Nah. I think it starts off dupish, but ends up asking something else. I *think*. Actually I am not quite sure what it ends up asking.

Comment: Cry in _Cry me a river_ is ditransitive.

Comment: @JasperLocke quite right :)

Comment: So, is it asking for someone to cry (for) me as much as a river? and Die (for) me a death that will be remembered forever?

Comment: @Jasper Locke. I'd analyse it differently, with 'a river' being a measure phrase (cf cost me a fortune), and thus not a DO. See John Lawler's comment at ['Is this a direct object or predicate complement?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218484/is-this-a-direct-object-or-predicate-complement). * _A river was cried [for] me by ..._

Answer (score 4):

It's generally makes more sense to say that clauses and not verbs are transitive or intransitive. However, this won't stop dictionaries or grammar books for language and linguistics students giving lists of verbs that they'll describe as 'transitive' or 'intransitive'. Having said that, it's also true that whether a *clause* is transitive or not is also contentious at times - because what is meant by *transitive* is not clearly defined. Because this is so, people often start arguing about it at cross-purposes.

The fact is that many verbs *tend* to take objects, predicative complements and all sorts of combinations of different types of complement. However, they only *tend* to. There are actually very few verbs that are only *transitive* or *intransitive*. These labels normally just describe a typical usage.

I sometimes say things like "*If someone wants to use an object with this kind of verb, then they really don't understand the true meaning of the verb in the first place*". The verb I often give as an example, is the verb *die*. Usually, if language learners, for example, want to use an object with the verb *die*, it's because they really want to convey the meaning of *kill*.

However, although *die* might seem a very (sic) intransitive verb, it can still be used perfectly well transitively in phrases such as *he died a horrible death* - as one of my students quite rightly pointed out to me. Most any verb that you can think of that seems intransitive can be used transitively, and the same goes for the other way round too. Almost any so-called transitive verb can be used *in*-transitively. Take the word *give*, a verb that is often wheeled out as an example of a transitive verb. We still find, of course, phrases such as:

- I'm fed up of just *giving, giving, giving* all the time.

Idioms, in particular, very often make use of complementation patterns that are idiosyncratic. In some ways the more unusual they are, the stronger effect they have. I have no statistical evidence, but I would wager that idiomatic usages have *far* more examples of 'transitive' verbs used intransitively and vice verse than other sentences.

In terms of *cry me a bucket*, I think everyone would understand that metaphor, whether or not  they recognised it as an idiom in its own right. For sure, you could also say:

- cry me a waterfall/ crocodile tear/ ocean/ vodka martini / dustbowl

and it would work as some kind of metaphor without there being any *grammatical* issue (though your literary ability might let you in for a kicking if it's as poor as mine).

So, my advice is to transitively smile a huge smile, and wonder at the weirdness of language. [ - including the fact that *weirdness* patently has the '*i*' and the '*e*' the wrong way round - but that's another topic ..]

*Hope this helps!*

Comment: How can a clause be transitive?

Comment: @JasperLocke Here's a shorter more digestible one. It's from a dictionary of grammatical terms, so only read the bit under Transitivity. (I accidentally read the whole page thinking *what's this got to do with transitivity*?)  [transitivity](http://languagetools.info/grammarpedia/transitivity.htm)

Comment: After a bit of mulling it over in my head, I came the other day upon a good verb to use as an almost-totally-intransitive one: _faint_. It’s perfectly idiomatic to say, “He died a horrible death”, but even with the best of efforts, I cannot get “She fainted a violent faint/fall/crunch/etc.” to sound idiomatic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I might steal that, if I may? (for the odd TEFL class that is)

Comment: Go right ahead. :-)

Comment: If by 'clauses and not verbs are transitive or intransitive' you mean 'verbs can only be considered to be used transitively or intransitively in given sentences', I think we'd all agree. And I agree that even then, individual usages can be hard to classify: I've seen 'The piano had a stool' cited as involving a DO, and not, by different analysts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The weirdest I've seen is H&P calling *five pounds* a DO in *it weighed five pounds*. Never been able to fathom that one...

Comment: I once came across a respected (till then) authority classifying 'she led him a merry dance' as a ditransitive usage. It's form over function.

Answer (score 1):

How intransitive can it be:

"He cried crocodile tears." appears to have a direct object.

Comment: But then 'He cried for hours.' doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

The essential point to hold onto here is that a transitive verb transposes the action from the subject to the object and therefore needs an object. That's what the 'trans' part means- across. 
More practically, the action of a verb can change the object it acts upon or not, and that's really the acid test. 
Think about an example such as, 'He ate a sandwich'. Clearly, the sandwich isn't in the same form after being eaten and so the action of eating is  transitive here. What about 'He stood on the table'? The table is in no way affected by the action so stood is intransitive. 
You can also imagine the sentence being spoken by someone entering a room with no prior context. If it makes sense then it's probably an intransitive verb. 'I've just kicked the....' This clearly needs an object to make sense so kicked must be transitive here. 'Listen!' Listen must be intransitive whereas 'Can you hear the...' Hear must be transitive. 
Grammar is very often practical rather than just a sense of meaningless rules when you get into it.

Comment: I think you're crying "wolf".