# Can the verb 'last' ever be ditransitive?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, indirect-objects, ditransitivity

> (1) That car should **last** you for ten years.
>
> (2) That car should **last** you ten years.

I think these two mean the same thing.

In (1), the verb 'last' is clearly monotransitive.

How about the verb 'last' in (2)?

Is it monotransitive or ditransitive?

### EDIT

This question is clearly different from the earlier question. Not only is the verb involved different, but the construction following the verb is different (e.g, unlike in the earlier question, there's the optional "for" following the verb).

Moreover, none of the four answers to the earlier question even solve its own problem. The highest scoring answer has only two votes when the question itself has as many as six votes. So, I don't know how any of the four answers that don't even solve its own problem can possibly be said to solve the problem in my question that has a clearly distinct problem.

Now, I don't know what Edwin Ashworth means by "John Lawler's analysis". If by that Edwin means John's comments to one answer there, John did mention something about "commercial transaction verb", which does not include the verb 'last' in any way.

Finally, Edwin says in his comment, "On some analyses, it's debatable whether 'you' should be considered a DO." I don't think that saying that it's debatable is answering any question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is this a direct object or predicate complement?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218484/is-this-a-direct-object-or-predicate-complement) (see John Lawler's analysis). On some analyses, it's debatable whether 'you' should be considered a DO.

Comment: I would classify *you* as dative and *(for) ten years* as adverbial, no transitivity needed.

Comment: @Anonym English has no dative, so I'm assuming you mean that *you* is an indirect object. It certainly plays the role of recipient, but indirect objects rarely appear in the absence of a direct object, and then the sense of the sentence provides the missing object. (*I told you*, for example).

Comment: In (1) "last" is monotranstive with "you" as Od  and the PP "for ten years" as temporal adjunct. By contrast, in (2) it is ditransitive with "you" as Oi and "ten years" as Od.

Comment: @deadrat Well, yes, I do mean indirect object, but from a practical perspective I'm not sure what the difference is, since the indirect object seems always to play a dative role.

Comment: If 'you' isn't considered a DO, ('You are lasted 10 years by it' is ungrammatical) and measure phrases aren't considered as objects, 'last' wouldn't even be considered transitive. But BillJ gives an alternative analysis (no doubt the CGEL stance). // The duplicate spells out one view of measure phrases. It's one answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't believe BillJ's comment above is the stance of CGEL, although I could be wrong.

Comment: @BillJ Your comment "in (2) it is ditransitive with "you" as Oi and "ten years" as Od", is it based on CGEL? If so, please give me the page number.

Comment: @BillJ    "That battery charge should last *the morning*"? Are there any respectable minority opinions that would consider "the morning" there a temporal adjunct?

Comment: This is different from the *you* in the ditransitive "I made you king."

Comment: Consider "It takes **the earth** (Oi)  **a little more than 365 days** (Od) to travel around the sun".

Comment: @BillJ Yes, but **to last** and **to take** are rather different types of verbs. Doesn't contemporary descriptive grammar concern itself with such differences when parsing an utterance to decide which role a phrase plays?

Comment: @DjinTonic You might consider that "made" is monotransitive in "I made you king", where "you" is direct object and "king" is objective predicative complement.

Comment: @BillJ Since you don't give me the page number, I don't think it's from CGEL. Re the verb 'take', I think it's quite a different usage. First, you cannot put a preposition before Od: *_It takes the earth **for** a little more than 365 days to travel around the sun_. Second, if you remove _a little more than 365 days_ and say _It takes the earth to travel around the sun_, it doesn't make sense or it means an entirely different thing.

Comment: @BillJ By contrast, you can put a preposition _for_ in _That car should last you ten years_ and say _That car should last you **for** ten years_ without changing the meaning of _last_. You can even use a different preposition phrase as in  _That car should last you **until 2030**_. Also, you can omit _ten years_ from _That car should last you ten years_ and say _That car should last you_ without changing the meaning of _last_.

Comment: @JK2 Note that, as in most though not all ditransitive clauses, you can omit the indirect object but not the direct object. My example was simply intended to show that measure expressions can be Od. Btw, the infinitival "to travel around the sun" is an adjunct, irrelevant here. Make what you will of CGEL.

Comment: "last" is similar to other verbs such as "serve" or "keep", as well as the informal "do": "that car should serve you (for) ten years", "that car should do you ten years". Suggesting "you" is the direct object. Intuitively, omitting "for" is more acceptable with some verbs than others, but I'm not sure if that indicates a different grammatical structure.

Comment: @StuartF I'm not sure in what way "last" and "serve" are similar. In your example, "you" is the recipient of "serve", so it's a direct object and it can't be omitted. But OP's "you" is not the recipient but the beneficiary of "last", and it can be easily omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are perfectly grammatical, both mean the same thing, and I think both share the same structure, too.  It's just that "for" is spoken in one case, and implied in the other.

"ten years" doesn't become an extra object.  It's an adverbial in both.