# Is "ran" transitive or intransitive in "The boy ran a long distance"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, transitive-verbs, intransitive-verbs

The sentence was "The boy ran a long distance."
I answered that the verb "ran" was intransitive. Is it correct ?

Comment: https://www.englishclub.com/esl-forums/viewtopic.php?t=27617

Comment: "Ran" is transitive and the noun phrase "a long distance" is its direct object.

Comment: See [Is this a direct object or predicate complement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218484/is-this-a-direct-object-or-predicate-complement/350291#350291) for a treatment of 'measure phrases'.

Comment: CGEL has 'The view taken here, however, is that the resistance of the verbs to passivisation does not provide convincing grounds for saying that the post-verbal NPs are not objects: passivisation does not provide either a necessary or a sufficient condition for object status.' The authors are gracious enough to concede that there are other views.

Comment: What has passivisation got to do with anything? The OP simply asked if the verb "run" was transitive or intransitive in their example. In any case "run" can occur in passive clauses, cf. The first sub-four- minute mile was run by Roger Bannister in 1954 .

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The verb 'run' is always intransitive when it has the sense of "To go with quick steps on alternate feet, never having both or (in the case of many animals) all feet on the ground at the same time" (according to [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168875?rskey=045Kv2&result=4#eid)). The phrase 'a long distance' functions as an adverb phrase that answers the question 'how far' rather than 'what'.

Comment: Hello, WindOwl. You'll see that Encarta analyses 'ran a long distance' differently (in line with CGEL, I believe). I favour the not-a-direct-object interpretation myself, but one needs a more authoritative grammar resource than a dictionary to argue one way or the other in this case.

Comment: What about OED, 2b: *b) To traverse or cover (a certain distance) by running*?

Answer (score -3):

transitive verb travel distance by running: to cover a particular distance while running
Microsoft® Encarta® 2008. © 1993-2007 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

3 a (1) : to pass over or traverse with speed  (2) : to run on or over in athletic competition  *runs the bases well*  *run the floor*  b : to accomplish or perform by or as if by running  *ran a great race*  *run errands*  c : to slip or go through or past  *run a blockade*  *run a red light*  d : to travel on (as a river) in a boat  *run the rapids* Merriam-Webster