# Emailed "with" an apology...?

Tags: word-usage

In today's USA today, the following sentence appeared:

***Delta later emailed the flight’s customers with an apology, according to the Aviation Herald.***

What is the ***with*** doing in that sentence?  I'm assuming this is a typo.  I would write the sentence without ***with***.  Am I missing something here?

The [article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/flights/todayinthesky/2016/02/01/delta-flight-diverts-after-alleged-fist-fight-attendants/79651508/).

Comment: Typos don't usually include an extra four letter word. It sounds fine to me.

Comment: It's correct.  The use of "with" in that sense is apparently something you're not familiar with, however.  If "Delta later *provided* the flight’s customers with an apology" that would no doubt make sense.  It works the same.

Comment: No, it's not extra; it sounds fine. One presents someone with something. He presented her with the medal of honor. But it is somewhat optional.

Comment: @medica Well, then is this just a matter of personal choice?  Personally, the preposition seems unnecessary.  I would just say "I emailed you an apology."  Why is the "with" preferred?

Comment: It's not preferred [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=email+me+the%2C+email+me+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cemail%20me%20the%3B%2Cc0).  I asked a [similar question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302590/what-are-some-give-type-verbs-that-cannot-undergo-straight-dative-alternation) a week ago

Comment: "I emailed you an apology" is probably more common, but it's really fine either way; "with" might be particularly appropriate if there was other content as well

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire I've seen this usage in a few places and to me is wrong...but that's just me...that's why I was asking...see what other users say about thius.

Comment: From the airline's standpoint, "emailed ... with" sounds a bit more formal and polite.  The line may have been (indirectly) copied from the airline's press release or some such.

Comment: @HotLicks the day I take writing lessons from an airline is the day I...

Comment: Trust me, they have people to write the stuff who are much better paid than you are.

Comment: @HotLicks No, they don't.

Comment: @HotLicks and since when did "better paid" mean better quality or more accurate information.  I suppose JK Rowling was better paid than Fitzgerald so perhaps I should starting teaching harry Potter.

Comment: What?  You don't think an airline magazine is right up there with, say, "The Economist", in its command of English and grasp of issues?  One wonders how correct the German was in GermanWings's apology.

Comment: I think it means, Delta emailed them and inside the email there was an apology. If it was just; emailed an apology, I would assume that the whole email was an apology. But from that sentence I understand that there was some other content together with an apology in the email.

Comment: @Grizzly I like that interpretation.  Put it in an answer and I'll vote it best.

Comment: Shamelessly posting my comment as an answer :)

Comment: @Grizzly fine by me.  I'm a satisfied customer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret it as, Delta emailed them and inside the email there was an apology. If it was just; emailed an apology, I would assume that the whole email was an apology. But from that sentence I understand that there was some other content together with an apology in the email.