# Can you use a ditransitive construction with the verb 'to attribute'?

Tags: verbs

Examples:

- John attributed his cold to his wife.
- Jane attributed wisdom to her father that he didn't really possess.

The above are standard transitive constructions.  Can I then properly say the following using a ditransitive construction?

Examples:

- John attributed his wife his cold.
- Jane attributed her father ('with'?) wisdom he didn't really possess.

Comment: I think you can just about get away with discarding ***with*** before the second object, particulary when the first object is a pronoun. So *We should avoid attributing them selfish motives* doesn't sound too unreasonable to me. But I don't like either of *your* examples, and I wouldn't recommend habitually trying to use ***attribute*** ditransitively.

Comment: It's not in my list of just under 80 verbs which may be used ditransitively / benefactively , but that's not conclusive. It's used ditransitively in a limited number of examples on the internet, some of which appear quite grammatical otherwise. I agree with everything FF says above.

Comment: Are you the same Benjamin Harman that hasn't logged on since January of this year. If you are, welcome back! If you're not, Hello newcomer :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - Yes, I'm the same one.  I haven't been on in a long time -- so long that I don't know what happened to my old account. I couldn't remember the user name. So this is a new account that I created because I have this grammar question I can't seem to find an answer for, which I'm not finding one here either.  Anyway, thanks for welcoming me back, Mari-Lou.

Comment: Hello, welcome back! You could, if you want, write to Stack Exchange via their [contact us](http://english.stackexchange.com/contact) link and ask them to merge both accounts. I've seen it done with others in your same situation. Up to you, of course.

Comment: You will find the linked questions helpful. [What's wrong with “I'll open you the door”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door) and [What are some give-type verbs that cannot undergo straight dative alternation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/302590/what-are-some-give-type-verbs-that-cannot-undergo-straight-dative-alternation)

Comment: It's a list I've compiled over the years: accord
afford
allocate
allow
appoint
ascribe
ask
assign
assure
award
bake
bet
bring
build
buy
call
catch
cause
charge 
choose
cook
cost
cut
deal
deliver
deny
design
do
draw
drop
earn
feed
find
fine
forgive
get
give
grant
guarantee
hand
hunt
keep
leave
lend
lose
make
name
offer
order
overpay
owe
pass
pay
permit
pick
play
prescribe
profit
promise
purchase
quote
read
refuse
render
save
sell
send
serve
set
show
spare
supply
take
teach
tell
throw
win
wish
write

Comment: ... Note (1) it's doubtless incomplete; (2) 'ditransitive' usually has a semantically-related requirement. 'He baked me a cake' would usually be labelled a 'benefactive' rather than a 'ditransitive' usage; note that 'for me' rather than 'to me' would be correct in the alternation. (3) 'Forgive us our trespasses' is arguably neither; (4) 'He took the dog a walk' and 'He led them a merry dance' are certainly neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct use of the ditransitive.
There are the Attributive Ditransitive Verbs. Wikipedia describes them well:
Attributive ditransitive Verbs
There is a different kind of ditransitive verb, where the two objects are semantically an entity and a quality, a source and a result, etc. These verbs attribute one object to the other. In English, make, name, appoint, turn into and others are examples:

The state of New York made Hillary Clinton a Senator.
I will name him Galahad.
 What is challenging is that the examples are actions that are relatively intangible.

Let's try "He gave the checkbook to his wife."
          "He gave his wife the checkbook."
From here, you can see that checkbook could be replaced with cold.

```
    "Jane gave the theater tickets to her father that he didn't have." 
    "Jane gave the theater tickets her father that he didn't have."
```

From here, theater tickets could be replaced with "the wisdom" or wisdom.

Comment: This misses the point that only certain verbs (eg 'give') may be used ditransitively.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it is okay:                                                        Attributive ditransitive Verbs
There is a different kind of ditransitive verb, where the two objects are semantically an entity and a quality, a source and a result, etc. These verbs attribute one object to the other. In English, make, name, appoint, turn into and others are examples:

The state of New York made Hillary Clinton a Senator.
I will name him Galahad.

Comment: @user183590 - Thanks for updating your answer.  The information you provided was really helpful.