# "make me a cup of coffee" vs "make a cup of coffee for me"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Actually, it's all in the title.

> 1. Would you **make me** a cup of coffee, please?
> 2. Would you **make** a cup of coffee **for me**, please?

Is there any difference either in the meaning or traditional usage?

Comment: Number 1 allows my father-in-law to respond, “Ok you’re a cup of coffee.”

Comment: As long as you wind up getting a cup of coffee out of it, either one's OK.  But only in that situation. A sentence like *_[Would you open me the door, please?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299)_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: Some of these decisions on ditransitivity / benefactiveness (?) are not held by everyone. 'Pick me some flowers' usually causes a divide.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks, got it. Should I delete the question or should it be market as a duplicate?

Comment: @ZverevEugene You're welcome. Don't worry about the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's wrong with "I'll open you the door"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door)

Answer (score -1):

If I got it right, the question is already answered here: [What's wrong with “I'll open you the door”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/175699)

I don't pretend to fully understand the concept of an **object** (`a cup of coffee` in my case) being either transferred or not from a **subject** (non-described state of the semi-finished coffee in my case) to an **indirect object** (`me` in my case). But I see enough to begin reading further.