# Is "she was peeled an orange (by me)" unacceptable in English?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice

Is "she was peeled an orange (by me)"  unacceptable in English when 'she' is interpreted as an intended recipient?

I found Kay (1996: 11-12) claims that "I'll peel you an orange" has two possible interpretations.

https://home.uni-leipzig.de/muellerg/kay96.pdf

[Interpretation 1] 'You' is treated as an intended recipient.

[Interpretation 2] 'You' is a kind of 'pleasee.' The sentence can be used, according to Kay, when I'll peel an orange in order to answer your desire to know whether my injured hand has regained its dexterity.

In his discussion, Kay contends that '*Madge was peeled an orange (adroitly) (by me).' is unacceptable in English. But this paper is more than 20 years old now.

I'd like to know this passive is still unacceptable both Interpretation 1 and 2.

Comment: It's weird, at the very least.

Comment: It sounds wrong.  What doesn't sound wrong is: "An orange was peeled for Madge (by me)."

Comment: The term for this is "word salad"—it's not a grammatical sentence, but it has pieces that sound like they should go together, but don't.

Comment: What if *'you'* is the one being peeled and *'an orange'* is a style of peeling? Like *I'll cook you al dente*. That'd be a third option, right?

Comment: I think a similar question was answered in elegant detail by John Lawler: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door. This may, then, be a duplicate.

Comment: I was wondering about that, too, and don't quite know what to say about this one. Certainly both senses are possible, as Kay suggests. Note that _I took the test for Bill_ does not do Dative, because Bill doesn't receive the test: *_I took Bill the test_.  But whereas Dative with _peel_ is unexceptionable -- even part of fixed phrases like _Peel me a grape_ -- Dative plus Passive isn't. I find *_She was peeled an orange_ quite unacceptable, even though _She was bought a book_ is fine with a benefactive _for_ source. There must be something more to the context.

Comment: @John Lawler : It's quite interesting _*she was peeled an orange_ is unacceptable while _she was bought a book_ is grammatical. I also found Svenonius (2004) observes that _the department chair was baked a cake_  is acceptable. (https://www.academia.edu/2679601/The_Zero_Level) So I assume it's a matter of idiomaticity or entrenchment level in language? Quite a confusing but interesting aspect of language.

Comment: @hiya I would certainly not say that *she was peeled an orange* is *unacceptable*. It's unusual, and somewhat open to interpretation, but it's not ungrammatical. (It kind of reminds me of the Monty Python killer rabbit that will *do you a treat*.)

Comment: @jjj : Your third option never occurred to me until I saw your post. In that interpretation, I suppose the example sentence is not an instantiation of the double object construction any more