# Why don't we have a preposition after "buy" in this sentence

Tags: prepositions

Why don't we have a preposition after *buy* in this sentence?

- *Each dollar in my asset column was a great employee,

  working hard to make more employees and buy the boss a new Porsche.*

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This might better fit the [English Language Learners StackExchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). To answer your question, I suggest you look up the concept of a "double object." For the verb *buy* here, "the boss" is the indirect object and "a new Porsche" is the direct object. In this construction, a preposition is not required.

Comment: Which preposition would you expect, and why?

Comment: Some verbs undergo the dative shift (He bought a cycle for me ⇔ He bought me a cycle) while some don't (He acquired a cycle for me ⇔ *He acquired me a cycle). Note that 'for' is dropped in for instance 'and buy the boss a new Porsche'.

Comment: You could optionally add *to* to make it *...and to buy the boss a new Porsche.*

Comment: Thank you a lot @TaliesinMerlin, today I learn the "double object verbs" grammar. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @JohnLawler I've expected the "for", so the sentence should be "...and buy for the boss a new Porsche"

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth for helping me to clear it.

Comment: Thank you @Davo <3

Comment: @LuanPham The _for_ marks a benefactive construction, not a dative (indirect object), which uses _to_ exclusively, when it uses a preposition at all. The original clause would be _(they) buy a Porsche for the boss_. The reverse order *_buy for the boss a Porsche_ is ungrammatical. [**Only** in case the boss winds up owning the Porsche](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90534/15299) can the clause undergo the Dative alternation, and produce _buy the boss a Porsche_. If you _take a bullet for the boss_, you can't say *_take the boss a bullet_.

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnLawler, today I know "dative"