# Can "donate" be used as a ditransitive verb?

Tags: word-usage, indirect-objects, ditransitivity

Are sentences like the following valid?

1. He donated the charity five hundred dollars.
2. She donated the children every penny she had.
3. We donated the library a large collection of books.
4. They won't donate the school any more supplies.
5. Would *you* donate your sister a kidney?

All of these *sound* perfectly natural to me. But I can't find this definition (or any similar examples) in any dictionary, and Huddleston & Pullum (2002) claim that "donate" can't be used with an indirect object. Am I crazy?

(I'm in the Northeast US, in case this is a regionalism.)

Comment: To be honest, none of those seem natural to me; I'd pot a 'to' after every one of those 'donates.' But I may be the crazy one.

Comment: In other words, does donate work like give?

Comment: @user66974 Yes.

Comment: "Donate" is _to_ only.

Comment: All examples amount to asking if baby formula is made for babies or with babies.

Comment: It doesn't work that way in California, for one.

Comment: _Donate_ takes an "indirect object" -- i.e, a receiver constituent -- but it does not undergo the Dative Alternation (the rule that relates _I gave him the book_ and _I gave the book to him_). Like _explain_, another 3-place verb with the same peculiarity: _He explained the answer to me,_ but not *_He explained me the answer._

Comment: One can say 'He donated five hundred dollars' just as one can say 'He explained the answer'. But colloquially, we do not accept a second object. 'He passed me the salt', however, is colloquially acceptable.

Comment: I'm *very* surprised to learn that this is nonstandard, but apparently people are unanimous that this is either a rare colloquial use (see the answer from @TinfoilHat) or just wrong (as the commenters here state).

Comment: In my experience "donate" cannot be used ditransitively. It can, of course, take a direct object but the recipient must be positioned in a PP: "He donated the prize money to a local charity". Note that "a local charity" is object of "to", not object of "donated".

Comment: @Heartspring I agree they don't seem natural, but I think that in BrE you would most likely say Someone donated something **to** a recipient. Example - "Joe donated books to a charity shop."

Comment: Incidentally, I would avoid using the term 'dative shift' since English does not have a dative case.

Comment: I wouldn't avoid using the term _Dative Shift_ or _Dative Alternation_, because it's the usual name for the construction. English doesn't have any cases, certainly not a dative, it's true. But it's a name, not a description. Not everyone is confused.

Comment: Perhaps, but it's a misleading name and hence best avoided.

Comment: Let's have an extended argument about whether to use commonly understood terms or technically correct ones. Obviously this isn't something reasonable people can disagree on. (Sarcasm.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In “Dative Shifts and Prime Rib Dinners,” linguist Neal Whitman examines the oral specimen *The townspeople wanted to donate us a prime rib dinner* and says:

> . . . it is usually noted that Latinate verbs such as *donate* do not
> undergo dative shift. Here are some sample sentences from a few papers
> I found by Googling “donate” and “dative shift”.
>
> <sub>[selected examples]</sub>
> *I donated money to the Red Cross.*
> **I donated the Red Cross money.*
> *I donated money to charity.*
> **I donated charity money.*

He then goes on to provide shifted examples from Google Books:

> <sub>[selected examples]</sub>
> *Next month someone may donate us an office.*
> *If you want to donate us something for dog food, . . .*
> *I’m so grateful you’d think she’s just donated me one of her kidneys.*

He concludes:

> I’m not saying that analyses of dative shift no longer need to exclude
> certain verbs from participating in this alternation. However, the
> canonical exclusion, *donate*, isn’t such a good example, after all.

<sub>Source: [Literal-Minded — Dative Shifts and Prime Rib Dinners](https://literalminded.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/dative-shifts-and-prime-rib-dinners/)</sub>

*I* won’t be doing this until further notice, though.

Comment: Marking this as solved because it explains why the examples *sound* OK to me, even though (as everyone has pointed out) this is very nonstandard.

Comment: This isn't the only case where my intuition disagrees with CGEL, incidentally: "I returned him his keys" and "I delivered him the package" also sound OK to me. Huh.

Comment: More from you-know-who here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90530/whats-wrong-with-ill-open-you-the-door

Comment: @alphabet: We may be of like mind! If so, perhaps you could [*upvote me an answer*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/90531/2637) if you haven't already done so!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. I suspect the answer is that, in informal speech, dative shift can spread to semantically similar words; so it could be used with "donate" by analogy with "give." Hmm...

Comment: That said, "open me the door" actually *does* sound wrong to me; I think you're right about the AmE/BrE split on the benefactive.

Comment: @alphabet: Personally, I have no problem at all with *Open me the door*. (But I can only tolerate *Open me the door **for Aunt Ethel*** on a *good* day! :)

Comment: It is interesting to note that the ones that "sound wrong" -> **I donated the Red Cross money*. **I donated charity money*. are noun - noun combinations and the ones that might pass muster if you squint -> *Next month someone may donate us an office*. *If you want to donate us something for dog food* use object case pronoun - noun. -- The there is I donated it them / them it.

Comment: *Open me a beer, will you?*

Comment: The invalidity of "I donated charity money" isn't really relevant. After all, "give" is ditransitive, and you can say "I gave money to charity," but not "I gave charity money."

Comment: Did Whitman notice that all the acceptable uses from googlebooks use a personal pronoun, not a regular NP?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. — Are you saying that, for example, *She donated me one of her kidneys* is acceptable but *She donated her cousin one of her kidneys* is not? That *Someone may donate us an office* is acceptable but *Someone may donate the company an office* is not?

Comment: More acceptable, yes.

Answer (score 3):

[The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/donate#:%7E:text=The%20computers%20were%20donated%20by,our%20old%20clothes%20to%20charity.&text=He%20donates%20some%20of%20his%20free%20time%20to%20volunteer%20work.) explains the usage of donate:

> : to give (money, food, clothes, etc.) in order to help a person or organization

***[+ object]***

> The computers were donated by local companies.
> We donated our old clothes ***to*** charity.
> people who donate money ***to*** political candidates
> He donates some of his free time ***to*** volunteer work.

***[no object]***

> Everyone is encouraged to donate.

Probably your examples are regional or informal usage.

Answer (score 3):

It's not something I would say as a fellow native speaker in the northeast US, and I didn't find any examples in in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) in the top 3 "recipient" collocates (*charity, campaign*, and *organization*). Excluding false positives, every example I found used "to". You can replicate this yourself by searching for [`DONATE` near `NOUN`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O2hi.png).

I found this grammar discussed in [On Shell Structures](https://books.google.com/books?id=h57IAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA166&dq=%22donated%20charity%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiuoarlwLP9AhUdF1kFHfWhDnA4ChC7BXoECAYQBw#v=onepage&q=%22donated%20charity%22&f=false).