Is "I don't have to prove you anything." grammatically correct?
Normally, we would say
I don't have to prove anything to you.
But we commonly say both
I don't have to show anything to you.
and
I don't have to show you anything.
In addition, we can say
I'll prove you wrong.
Why is the usage different?

I'm not sure but you might benefit from the late John Lawler's top-rated answer. IIRC, that is somewhat along the same lines as this question.

This https://english.stackexchange.com/q/90530/405662

I would say that it's idiomatically incorrect because 'prove someone something' is used to mean 'prove them to be something', not 'prove a fact to them'. For instance: prove him innocent - prove them wrong.

Very similar, but exploring '': prove me that X is so / prove to me that X is so / confirm one's belief that X is so.

While "show [something] to Jane" and "show Jane [something]" are synonymous, the phrases are not so when "prove" replaces "show": the subject of the proof is Jane in "proving Jane wrong" but not in "proving [blah blah] to Jane" or "proving to Jane [that blah blah]".

Not all matches are for the specific usage being queried here, but there are lots of instances of the sequence prove you this in Google Books that do relate to it.

If the intended sense of the sentence is "I don't have to prove anything to you," the wording as proposed is ungrammatical. If the intended sense of the sentence is "I don't have to prove you to be anything"—that is, "I don't have to prove that you are anything"—the wording as proposed is grammatical. Consider this exchange: Person A: "I dare you to prove me a liar." Person B: "I don't have to prove you anything." The phrase "to be" is implicit in both statements—after "me" in Person A's challenge, and after "you" in Person B's rejoinder.

"I'll prove you wrong." is an example of "I'll prove [(pro)noun] [adjective]" where there is a "to be" that is understood grammatically as to be properly part of this sentence: "I'll prove [noun] to be [adjective]."  (Of course, many other pronouns and verbs could begin such a sentence in lieu of "I'll prove".)

I've found a couple of examples:


prove them the fact that they can go nowhere without Iran's participation [Ali  Jalilian addressing an open session of the parliament on Tuesday, Ali Jalilian; Tasnim News Agency]



...
I love thee – then How well is that?
As well as Jesus?
Prove it me
That He – loved Men –
As I – love thee –   [Emily Dickenson; Fascicle 32;
1863]

used as, I suppose, a ditransitive rather than benefactive ('to' not 'for' probably involved in the paraphrase) construction, as with the impeccable

give him the news that he has been offered the job.

But even though ditransitive/benefactive usages seem to be on the increase (take for example the delightful 'hum me it'!?; queried by Maxwell in one of Trow's crime novels), I'd say this one is non-standard and better avoided. As said , examples are rare, and of the two here, one may be influenced by Subcontinental English, and one is dated and in lyrics/verse.
Internet examples, as stated, are exceedingly rare, and Google ngrams flatline for 'prove it them' and show only false positives for 'prove them it', though 'prove it to them' is in evidence.

That first one is an oversight or speech error he probably would not have made in writing. It's really not grammatical in English.

All the evidence I see is "not grammatical in (older) American English". To my BrE ear, there's no problem.

I'm far from happy with it, FF, but a bland 'it's not grammatical' fails to impress me. I suspect a Quirk-Svartvik type acceptability test with an international panel of Anglophone linguists would bring in a split verdict.

The axis being subject to testing is fully gradable - ownership-possession-benefit-proxy-with somebody in mind. So results are going to be squishy. I can turn her the kettle on or turn her the light on, but not turn her the charm on (which would presumably be done for my benefit). And phrasal verbs can be messy. Turn over the records to her. Turn the records over to her. Turn her over the records. Turn her the records over.
